# Update site for eclipse not working

Tags: eclipse, nusmv, nuseen

the nuseen update site for eclipse is not working.

[image]

Comment: At ~4,000 rep you must be realize that this doesn't even count as a question?

Comment: @LukePark After 20 years, couldn't they make syntax highlighting easy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deselect the 'Group items by category' check box near the bottom of the display and the contents will be shown.